# What exactly happens when I call a web service method using PHP::SOAP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Say I have a simple client/server scenario with one method:

```
// client code
$client = new SoapClient("service.wsdl");
$result = $client.getPi();

...

// server code
function getPi(){
   return 3.141;
}
$server = new SoapServer("service.wsdl");
$server.addFunction("getPi");
$server.handle();
```

Am I right in thinking that when the client makes a call to the `getPi()` method the `addfunction()` gets called everytime? Is this really how PHP SOAP web services work? Or is there some caching going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code will be executed each time a request is made to the webservice -- which means that, yes, the `addfunction()` will get called each time.

But calling that function should not take that long *(or that much resources)*, compared to the time it takes for a request to go through the network, anyway *(web-service = remote call = using an HTTP request = not that fast at all ^^ )* ;-)